# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

...перед союзом "и" в предложении: "Это и радость, и восторг(,) и т.п."
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, если тут имеет место перечисление того, чем является "это", то нужна. Например: "это и радость, и восторг, и наслаждение".

Answer (score 0):

Для точного ответа нужен полный контекст, а не часть предложения.

Comment: Это выражение просто заключено в скобки именно в таком виде.